# pwmconfig doesn't configure the fan

Tags: fan

Want to control  my  fan  speed. Tried `pwmconfig` but didn't work.

I get this

```
hwmon1/pwm3 is currently setup for automatic speed control
```

This one (hwmon1/pwm3) is my noise maker. Need it in manual mode, and also  at the end of `pwmconfig`,configuration option is missing, I mean out of 5 option, I get only 4, also it seems /etc/fancontrol is emty.

edit-2

```
    sudo pwmconfig
[sudo] password for seebox: 
# pwmconfig version 3.6.0
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

Found the following devices:
   hwmon0 is coretemp
   hwmon1 is it8718

Found the following PWM controls:
   hwmon1/pwm1           current value: 254
   hwmon1/pwm2           current value: 254
   hwmon1/pwm3           current value: 254
hwmon1/pwm3 is currently setup for automatic speed control.
In general, automatic mode is preferred over manual mode, as
it is more efficient and it reacts faster. Are you sure that
you want to setup this output for manual control? (n) yes

Giving the fans some time to reach full speed...
Found the following fan sensors:
   hwmon1/fan1_input     current speed: 4218 RPM
   hwmon1/fan2_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!

Warning!!! This program will stop your fans, one at a time,
for approximately 5 seconds each!!!
This may cause your processor temperature to rise!!!
If you do not want to do this hit control-C now!!!
Hit return to continue: 

Testing pwm control hwmon1/pwm1 ...
  hwmon1/fan1_input ... speed was 4218 now 3358
    no correlation

No correlations were detected.
There is either no fan connected to the output of hwmon1/pwm1,
or the connected fan has no rpm-signal connected to one of
the tested fan sensors. (Note: not all motherboards have
the pwm outputs connected to the fan connectors,
check out the hardware database on http://www.almico.com/forumindex.php)

Did you see/hear a fan stopping during the above test (n)? n

Testing pwm control hwmon1/pwm2 ...
  hwmon1/fan1_input ... speed was 4218 now 3169
    no correlation

No correlations were detected.
There is either no fan connected to the output of hwmon1/pwm2,
or the connected fan has no rpm-signal connected to one of
the tested fan sensors. (Note: not all motherboards have
the pwm outputs connected to the fan connectors,
check out the hardware database on http://www.almico.com/forumindex.php)

Did you see/hear a fan stopping during the above test (n)? n

Testing is complete.
Please verify that all fans have returned to their normal speed.

The fancontrol script can automatically respond to temperature changes
of your system by changing fanspeeds.
Do you want to set up its configuration file now (y)? y
What should be the path to your fancontrol config file (/etc/fancontrol)? 
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...

Select fan output to configure, or other action:
1) Change INTERVAL     3) Save and quit
2) Just quit           4) Show configuration

select (1-n):
```

Comment: post the output of `pwmconfig` in an edit.

Comment: Oky              ..............

Comment: I mean run `pwmconfig`, copy the output, edit this question, paste the output at the end, then select the output and press the {} Sample Code button and save it.

Comment: Odd that it is not enabling pwm3 for testing.  Can you manually set `/sys/devices/platform/it8718/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm3_enable` to 1 and then try it?  Keep track of what it was set to before incase you need to revert it quick.  Can then set `/sys/devices/platform/it8718/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm3` to a value between 0-255 if its working.  The path might need a little adjusting, just guessing from the info that is here.

Comment: Also post the contents of `/sys/devices/platform/it8718/hwmon/hwmon1/`, you might be able to configure the bios settings for what temps and speeds it runs at.

Comment: you mean this one `/sys/devices/platform/it87.656/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm3_enable ` right? if i open it with nano i get the following `error Error writing lock file ./.pwm3_enable.swp: Permission denied` but i can change to 1 though

Comment: @rtaft Thanks a lot.It worked! You are a life saver!I invested about 8 hour before asking the question here.What a waste of time......Thanks again.

Comment: I'll post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like pwm3 is being skipped during the test.  Try enabling it by editing the file `/sys/devices/platform/it87.656/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm3_enable` as root and set it's value to 1.  Then run `pwmconfig` again.  You can also manually set the fan speed by editing `/sys/devices/platform/it87.656/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm3` and setting it to a value between 0-255.